# How to get Id in GroupBy Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

**Table name** Transaction(Id,Account_Id,Type,Process,Credit,Date)

The result should show the "Id" where there are more than one record with same Account_Id, Type and Process with same date.

```
Select Account_Id 
  ,count(Account_Id)
from Transaction
Where Date = '@Date'
Group By Transaction.Type,
Transaction.Process,
Transaction.Account_Id
Having Count(Account_Id)>1
```

This, gives records of Account_Id with more than 1 entry. How can I retrieve the "Id" in same SQL? I can't use it because of "Group By" clause. Any alternate solution also be helpful.

Comment: what do you mean by : How can I retrieve the "Id" in same SQL?

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the expected result. The most obvious question is: if there are multiple rows, which ID do you want?

Comment: All Id's, Here Id is unique key

Comment: You can't group by and show all ids - please show some sample data to illustrate

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to retrieve all your columns based from this result.

```
SELECT * FROM Transaction WHERE Account_Id IN (
    Select Account_Id    
    from Transaction
    Where Date = '@Date'
    Group By Transaction.Type,
    Transaction.Process,
    Transaction.Account_Id
    Having Count(Account_Id)>1) as t1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `STRING_AGG` function to get a comma separated list of IDs as follows:

```
Select string_agg(Transaction.id,',') as ids,
  Transaction.Account_Id,
  Transaction.Process,
  Transaction.Type,
  ,count(Account_Id)
from Transaction
Where Date = '@Date'
Group By Transaction.Type,
Transaction.Process,
Transaction.Account_Id
Having Count(Account_Id)>1;
```

Or, if you want all column data then:

```
SELECT * FROM Transaction WHERE (Account_Id, type, process) IN (
    Select Account_Id, type, process   
    from Transaction
    Where Date = '@Date'
    Group By Transaction.Type,
    Transaction.Process,
    Transaction.Account_Id
    Having Count(Account_Id)>1) as t1
```